# Can you use combineReducers to compose deep state reducers?

Tags: redux

Redux docs suggest using `normalizr` to design the shape of the state like this:

```
{
  entities: {
    cards: {
      42: {
        id: 42,
        text: 'Hello',
        category: 2
      },
      43: {
        id: 53,
        text: 'There?',
        category: 1
      },
    }
    categories: {
      1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Questions'
      }
      2: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Greetings'
      },
    }
  },
  filter: 'SHOW_ALL',
  allCardsList: {
    isFetching: false,
    items: [ 42, 43 ]
  },
}
```

Naturally, this would split into three composable reducers (`filter`, `allThingsList` and `entities`), but it seems to me that I'd want to write separate reducers for `entities.cards` and `entities.categories`.

Is there a way to split management of entities into subreducers that would allow composition like this:

```
let rootReducer = combineReducers({
   entities: {
      things,
      categories
   },
   filter,
   allCardsList
});
```

Are there any advantages to keeping the `cards` and `categories` in `entities`, instead of keeping on the root level (which will allow composition using `combineReducers`)?

```
{
  cards: { ... },
  categories: { ... },
  filter: 'SHOW_ALL',
  allCardsList: { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to split management of entities into subreducers that would allow composition like this?

Sure! `combineReducers()` just gives you a reducer so you can use it several times:

```
let rootReducer = combineReducers({
   entities: combineReducers({
      things,
      categories
   }),
   filter,
   allCardsList
});
```

The [shopping-cart example in Redux repo](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/shopping-cart) demonstrates this approach.

> Are there any advantages to keeping the cards and categories in entities, instead of keeping on the root level?

It’s up to you but I find the structure you suggest easier to work with. It’s indeed easier for understanding to group all entities under a single key, and it is possible with `combineReducers()` as I show above.

Comment: Seems obvious now, if I think of the implementation of `combineReducers`. Thanks!